# Non-trivial logic function to CMOS schematic

Tags: digital-logic, cmos

I wanted to implement the function:

$$Y = \neg (A \land (B \lor C))$$

This is what I came up with, it looks correct to me but I would like  a second opinion on that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyXcqJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 'it looks correct" - I've had many circcuits that looked correct but turned out to be wrong - that is what simulators are for

Comment: sorry I dont know how to simulate this or any kind of circuit

Comment: Yet you entered your circuit into a simulator. I'm not an expert on digital simulation, but you could easily just write out a truth table for this logic function, and then do a DC operation point analysis to find all the output voltages of the different nodes (And thus your output) as a function of the input. A lot of simulators will even allow parametric sweep with which you could do the entire simulation of this in one run.

Comment: sorry I thought the tool was just for designing schematics. can you maybe link me where I can get started quickly to simulate the circuit ?

Comment: How about the "simulate this circuit" button next to the image?

Comment: I can't . But just google "SPICE Simulation" or something similar and do some research. Learning how to work with SPICE simulators is a valuable skill, as these types of simulators are both the industry standard (HSPICE, Spectre, ...) but also free versions exist (LTSpice). 
As @BrianDrummond points out: there is a button right by the image, perhaps look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your drawing, I derive this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSFvmB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your 10T implementation is correct.

There are alternative 6T implementations as an OAI complex gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu4vGx.png)</sup>

The OAI could be as drawn or the nFETs can be rearranged.

(Note that the bulk nodes of the stacked FETs are drawn inappropriately.  I didn't intend to imply these are discrete ICs with the source and bulk nodes shorted... this is just what I pulled from the library.)