# Implementing a logical function to a circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, cmos

[image]

This is an exercise in the book **Introduction to computing systems from bits and gates to C/C++ & beyond** by *Yale N. Patt and Sanjay J. Pattel*.

It asks to label the inputs of that transistor-level circuit so that the circuit does the same work of the Y function, I did manage to label them by intuition and made sure that my labeling is correct by comparing case by case the circuit to the truth table of the Y function as shown in the screenshot above, and I found that the circuit is indeed the implementation of the Y function but I don't understand how they designed it.

My question is: Is there any methodical way to find the correct labeling or even to design the whole circuit? Because I tried to rewrite the Y function (as shown in the screenshot) and indeed I managed to see that A is NANDed with something, because this circuit has the overall form of a NAND transistor-level circuit but I couldn't see how B and C are ORed. So if I was asked to implement the circuit of this Y function I wouldn't do it in this simple way in the exercise but I would rather make the OR gate between B and C and then I will NAND the result with A as shown in my drawing below:

[image]

So how did they manage to make the circuit for the Y function so simple, is there any method or trick they use to simplify such circuits?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you see serial O-A or A-O in your gate-level implementation, you can probably fold the serial gates into a single *complex gate.*

The complex gate pictured is an OAI21 or OAI12 in somewhat standard complex gate nomenclature.  That is OR-AND-INVERT, 2 inputs to the OR of `B+C`, 1 additional A input to the AND of `B+C · A`, and then an inversion. ( `Y = NOT ( A AND (B OR C ) )` is OAI21 ... if you read from right to left. )

How do you recognize this when reducing a SOP logic function?  You look for the OA or AO patterns.  There's actually no guarantee that when you group terms (factorization) that you'll find the most efficient transistor level implementation.  It's a heuristic process, as far as I know.

That said, if you can reduce a function to a single complex gate, there will be 2T per input.  In this case, 6T for 3 inputs.  You can't do better than that.  So try to reduce the total number of input literals through grouping terms, and look for AO or OA.  It's also ideal if the entire function is inverted, since and OAI21 is a 6T one stage gate while an OA21 is 8T, because it's an OAI21 and an inverter.

In this case:

- `Y = ~A + ~B~C` From Karnaugh Map  (An AO21 + 3 INV --> 8T+6T.)
- `Y = ~(A · (B + C))`  From DeMorgan's.   6T OAI21.

Another good example is the carry output in a full adder is an 10T AO22:  `Cout = Cin·A + Cin·B`  It's ANDs within an OR.  Or, DeMorgan it to get a smaller 8T OAI22, though you'd need to invert all 3 inputs, so it'd be bigger at 14T total.

I also have a [factorization example in this answer.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138879/transistor-count-in-nand-or-nor-implementation-of-boolean-algebra/163075#163075)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I'm sorry I'm still new to electronics and didn't understand any of the acronyms you used: A, O, OAI12, OAI21 ...etc. Can you please edit your answer by giving the full form of all the acronyms you used, I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: OAI = OR-AND-INVERT (which *is* there).    Invert being a synonym for 'not'.  Or/and don't have synonyms.   SOP is 'sum or products' in this context, which hopefully is in your text.   The complex gate nomenclature, though, is more from industry where it's used in standard cells.

Comment: but how about T?

Comment: @oabdullae - *transistor.*  Sorry!   Like 6T SRAM cell is 2 PFET and 4 NFET.